# iframe zoom out issue trigger scroll selenium java

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, iframe, java-8

I am trying to capture a snapshot from a large tableau report that has a huge iframe. In order to capture the full screen I need to zoom out. With a regular url pages the following code work perfectly, but when it comes to iframe

```
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom = '50%'");
```

Doesn't work its charm, it zoomed the iframe container to 50% but the content text size stays the same.

Then I added

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")));
```

Which help directed the zoom to that iframe specifically, but triggered a scroll.

Here is the code:

```
@Component
public class TableauReportingPage {

    @Autowired
    private BrowserCommands browserCommands;

    @Autowired
    private WebDriverService webDriverService;


    public void openExistingResource(String url) throws Exception{
        WebDriver driver = webDriverService.openNewBrowser();
        driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1650,950));
        driver.navigate().to(url);
        Thread.sleep(20000);
        driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")));
        Thread.sleep(20000);
//        for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
//            System.out.println(i);
//            new Actions(driver)
//                    .sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.SUBTRACT)
//                    .perform();
//            browserCommands.findElementsById("viz-client-container").
//                    sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.SUBTRACT));
//        }
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        executor.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom = '50%'");
        Thread.sleep(20000);

   }

    public File getScreenshot(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return browserCommands.getScreenshot();
    }
}
```

here is the before picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3ZPv.png)

here is after executing the code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsBkB.png)

Any idea how to code and zoom iframe properly to review all objects for screenshot?

Comment: Could you instead provide a screenshot/codepen/jsfiddle of the current result (instead of drawing it with lines) and maybe even the expected result?

Comment: zooming out to take a screencap is ok but have you tried to use Firefox Screen capture APIs to take full page screenshots? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture

Comment: @Naveen sorry im using chrome only..

Comment: @Rojo I will have to simulate the report since I can't show the real data. But the idea is able to zoom in the iframe to capture all content in one screenshot.

Comment: @Rojo Pictures were uploaded : )